# Remove elements from stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I have a button, when pressed it adds a textbox and a listbox to a stackpanel and adds this stackpanel to another stackpanel named "stackPanelAdd". Just like this:

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();   
    ListBox lb = new ListBox();

    tb.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 0);
    lb.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 0);
    lb.Height = 200;

    sp.Children.Add(tb);
    sp.Children.Add(lb);

    stackPanelAdd.Children.Add(sp);
}
```

How do I remove the last children in the stackpanel "stackPanelAdd"?
Should I use something like stackPanelAdd.children.Remove? if so then how do i get the last element in the stackpanel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
if (stackPanelAdd.Children.Count>0)
{
  stackPanelAdd.Children.RemoveAt(stackPanelAdd.Children.Count-1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is not a good idea, if you stick to this method things will probably get very messy sooner or later. When dealing with items that can be added and removed in WPF you will want to use an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) of some kind on top of panels (you can change the panel using the [`ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) property, by default it will be a `StackPanel`).

The creation of the controls can also be improved by using [data templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) and [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) which are core mechanisms that you should become familiar with.

An example:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,5,5,0"/>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="5,5,5,0" Height="200"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here `Data` is a source collection which should implement [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx), then you can just remove an item from that collection and its corresponding StackPanel will be gone. The items in `Data` should contain the bound properties `Name` and `Items` which you then can assign values to or get entered text from (the class should implement [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), read more about those things in the [article on data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)).

Comment: This is a good (& the right) answer, but it'd be a heckuva answer if you included the C# side with `Data` in it. I think the reason answers like Milan's pop up so often in WPF & UWP etc is that MS' documentation is not especially focused & quick hacks are much easier to grok. There are 7700 words at the article on data binding, give or take, and no clear example that I saw for the back half of your answer. It reads [almost] like Java docs from 2000. (To be clear, I think that's a MS failure, not yours -- it could be there. It's just a needle in a haystack of examples problem.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var lastControl = stackPanelAdd.Children.LastOrDefault(); 
//Last is defined in System.Linq.Enumrable
if(lastControl != null)
    stackPanelAdd.Children.Remove(lastControl);
```

Comment: Can't get the Last() function to work. Is there a reference that i need to you?

Comment: as I had mentioned you will have to import/use System.Linq

Comment: You want LastOrDefault() or you could get an exception

Answer (score 1):

@Milan Halada's answer worked for me with a little change,

```
while (stackPanelAdd.Children.Count>0)
{
  stackPanelAdd.Children.RemoveAt(stackPanelAdd.Children.Count-1);
}
```

so, it removes all the children and then i add new children to it dynamically using for loop, with new data.